# Show select option error

Tags: html, select

Please help me solve this problem, all files are spelled correctly, this select not working in Google browser
[image: images]

Comment: Wish I understood even a small part of it :)

Comment: What exactly does it do wrong? And obviously, What do you want it to do? Can you show relevant code?

Comment: I'm opening Google translate now... should have what "not working" means soon. ;)  Dan, you could always clarify that part, too.

Comment: I assume your charset is wrong. Which charset are you using for this HTML file?

Comment: I do not know English and translated by  Google translate...
 Padarom <meta charset="UTF-8"> is used

Comment: Flattened my snarky joke.  You say it does not work.  For something to fail to work, there exists something which is not being completed in the way desired.  Without that information we can only guess at your problem.

Comment: The source code contains a list of cities but browser displays Hieroglyphic

Comment: Do you have something like `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` in the HTML?  Is the file saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Jeremy Miller - yes : http://s29.postimg.org/9mifiirdz/ssssss.png

Comment: How about actually copying the code in here, instead of screenshoting it?

Comment: Yes, Ms. Nobody is right about that being very helpful.  And do you know for 100% certain that the *file* is UTF-8?  Is the data coming from a database?  An is it UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: this is test page: http://factorweb.md/test/test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for giving the link!  The problem is due to the Lato font being applied on the body which is used to display the dropdown when in the dropdown state (and not in the closed state since you have a font applied to the `SELECT` itself).  Once the Lato font is removed from line 68 of custom.css, your text will display appropriately.

All the encoding checked out.  Not all fonts have all symbols and that was what was getting you.

Either find a more complete implementation of the font or choose one which contains all of the needed characters.

Comment: Now, by way of comment, I had not seen such a difference before, so glad we all persisted!

Comment: thanks man https://i.chzbgr.com/maxW500/1698892544/h6794DA9F/